# Read even numbered files in python

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I have files named as file_1.txt,file_2.txt,file_3.txt ... till file_589.txt in a folder. I want to make a loop to read only the even numbered files and concatenate them. **Concatenation is not the issue** . How do we read the files ?

Comment: Do you mean, given a string `file_N.txt`, you want to tell if `N` is even?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you give us a code example of what you've already tried?

Comment: @bereal No, to read files only if N is even.

Comment: @sigma1510 Hey thanks! I am new to python so I didn't know what to use and where to start with the code, so I don't really have an example

Comment: @r3tr0 assuming that you know how to read files, it all boils down to figuring out if the number in the string is even. Which in turn boils down to extracting a number from a string.

Comment: Yes exactly @bereal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the `os` module.

- Change your directory to the folder conatining the files using `os.chdir()`.
- List all the files in that folder using `os.listdir()`. This will give names of files in a list.
- Iterate over that list and check if the filename ends with even number.

```
for i in os.listdir():
    if int(i.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]) % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
        # You can open the file and Do your concatenation here.
```

If you need a one-liner:

```
even_files = [x for x in os.listdir() if int(x.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0])%2 == 0]
```

Comment: The files are named as  "**AA_BBBB_HT40-100_1**, **AA_BBBB_HT40-100_2**, **AA_BBBB_HT40-100_3** .......... **AA_BBBB_HT40-100_'n'** " where n is the integer we are considering . What are the changes I should make?

Comment: It says " invalid literal for int() with base 10: 204.txt ". I just took 201,202,203,204 in a folder for testing.

Comment: Use this ```i.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]``` instead of ```i.split('_')[-1]```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `pathlib` module and string manipulation:

```
import pathlib

dirname = pathlib.Path('./myfolder')

files = [file for file in dirname.glob('*.txt')
                  if int(file.stem.split('_')[1]) % 2 == 0]
```

`file.stem` is the final path component, without its suffix. For instance, `files/file_10.txt`, `stem` is `file_10`.

```
>>> files
[PosixPath('files/file_6.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_4.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_18.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_20.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_2.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_12.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_10.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_8.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_14.txt'),
 PosixPath('files/file_16.txt')]
```